# Error en dataTable PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, grocery-crud

Estoy haciendo un formulario en *PrimeFaces*, y al realizar una operación *CRUD* me trabaja sin problemas, pero al listar la información desde un `dataTable`, no me muestra ninguna información, en consola me indica que la información se consultó exitosamente.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/paginas/plantilla/plantilla.xhtml">

<ui:define name="tituloPagina"> 
    <h:outputText value="Gestion de Tipo de Identificacion" />
</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="cuerpo">

        <h:form>
            <p:messages id="capaMensajes" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true"></p:messages>
            <p:fieldset legend="formulario datos tipo de identificacion" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">

            <p:toolbar>
                <f:facet name="right">
                    <p:commandButton value="Limpiar" id="cbLimpiar" action="#{TipoIdentificacionBean}" ></p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Crear" id="cbCrear" action="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.crear()}" ></p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Actualizar" id="cbActualizar" action="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.actualizar()}" ></p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Eliminar" id="cbEliminar" action="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.eliminar()}" ></p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Consultar" id="cbConsultar" action="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.consultar()}" ></p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
            </p:toolbar>
                <br/>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                <h:outputLabel for="itNombre" value="Nombre Tipo Identificacion" />
                <p:inputText  id="itNombre"  value="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.tipoIdentificacion.nvNombre}">
                <p:tooltip for="itNombre" value="Campo para Ingresar el Nombre del tipo de Identificacion"
                 showEffect ="explode" hideEffect="explode"></p:tooltip></p:inputText>  
            </p:panelGrid>
            </p:fieldset>

            <p:fieldset legend="Lista de Resultados" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                <p:dataTable value="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.consultarTodos()}" var="tipoIdentificacion" id="idTablaTiposIdentificacion" 
                 emptyMessage="No existen Tipos de Identificacion para mostrar">

                <p:column headerText="Codigo"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.inCodigo}" />
                <p:column headerText="Nombre"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.nvNombre}" />
                <p:column headerText="Fecha Creacion"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.dtFechaCreacion}" />
                <p:column headerText="Fecha Modificacion"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.dtFechaModificacion}" />
                <p:column headerText="Fecha Eliminacion"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.dtFechaEliminacion}" />
                <p:column headerText="Usuario Eliminacion"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.segUsuarioByInCodigoUsuarioEliminacion}"/>
                <p:column headerText="Usuario Creacion"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.segUsuarioByInCodigoUsuarioCreacion}"/>
                <p:column headerText="Usuario Modificacion"></p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tipoIdentificacion.segUsuarioByInCodigoUsuarioModificacion}"/>               

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:fieldset>       
        </h:form>   
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aporta el codigo de TipoIdentificación y TipoIdentificacionBean

Comment: Este es el Bean

Comment: @ReyJuanjo  Este es el Bean de consultarTodos  public ArrayList<SegTipoIdentificacion> consultarTodos() { 
  ArrayList<SegTipoIdentificacion>listaRetorno = null;
  try {
   TipoIdentificacionFachada tipoIdentificacionFachada = LocalizadorBean.obtenerBean(TipoIdentificacionFachada.class);
   tipoIdentificacionFachada.consultarPorFiltro(null);} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return listaRetorno;
 }

}  Lo estoy trabajano con Hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz referencia a una propiedad del bean, por ejemplo listaIdentificaciones, que esta se cargue en un método de inicialización marcado con @PostConstruct, y crea get/set. Algo así:

`...
private List<SegTipoIdentificacion> listaIdentificadores;
...
@PostConstruct
public void init (){
   listaIdentificadores = consultarTodos();
}
public List<SegTipoIdentificacion> getListaIdentificadores(){
   return listaIdentificadores;
}`

y en el xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.listaIdentificadores}"
```

Comment: Solucionado con el ejemplo que me diste así quedo el codigo, en el Data <p:dataTable var="tipoIdentificacion" value="#{TipoIdentificacionBean.listaTipoIdentificacion}"  y en el Bean private ArrayList<SegTipoIdentificacion> listaTipoIdentificacion;

 public ArrayList<SegTipoIdentificacion> getListaTipoIdentificacion() {
  return listaTipoIdentificacion;
 } y el Constructor public TipoIdentificacionControlador() {
  tipoIdentificacion = new SegTipoIdentificacion();
  consultarTodos(); 
 }

Comment: Marca la respuesta como correcta, por favor!

Answer (score 0):

Para que pueda mostrar tus datos en la vista, necesitas inicializar tu constructor, esto lo haces con la anotación `@PostConstruct`, además de que este método debe de contener una lista o ya sea un `Map`, para que pueda mostrar los valores deseados. Esto ya es a gusto del desarrollador.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    nombre = "Hola primefaces";
}
```